# xaf devexpress controls are disabled in DetailView

Tags: xaf

I'm viewing a DetailView when I click a button. My problem is I can't write anything to controls, they are disabled although I did:

```
view.ViewEditMode = ViewEditMode.Edit;
view.Model.AllowEdit = true;
```

that. What could be the cause?

Comment: When your view is opened by normal means (i.e., the "New Action" in the ListView), the sample problem happens?

Comment: Also, if you have expanded some properties (ExpandObjectMembersAttribute), check if your referenced object is created.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the particular view could have been modified in the module model.DesignedDiffs.xafml, or the same named file in the Web or Win module or in the Web or Win xafml module.

Start with the most descendant version, and check the properties for the view, and work back to the module's xafml.